# Хранение даты последнего добавления записи в БД - как отследить изменение?

Tags: php, архитектура, mysql

На сайте добавляется контент. Чтобы не делать запрос к большой таблице, была создана отдельная таблица **timeActive** с меткой последнего добавления контента.

Допустим, пользователю отобразили последний контент списком из 20 записей. Можно взять метку времени самой свежей записи и ее запомнить. Затем, при следующем получении записей, делать запрос в таблицу **timeActive**, где делать запрос на:

`WHERE timeActive.time >= savedTime`

Вопрос - где хранить **savedTime** от последней свежей записи?

Comment: При выборе последних 20 записей можно обнулять поле **timeActive**. А при добавлении новой записи - изменять на время добавления.

Comment: Совсем не понятно, что у вас в таблице timeActive хранится. Если это кортежи вида {ИД_контента | время изменения} и вы по ним осуществляете поиск и выборку самых свежих записей, то savedTime из вашего примера должен передавать клиент, делающий запрос к БД.

Соответственно храниться он должен на клиенте

Comment: Я с Вами согласен, но чтобы получить этот savedTime, то нужно обратится к базе.
_____

В timeActive хранится метка времени последней добавленной записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите в сессию время последнего обновления контента у юзера в UNIX формате.
По поводу дополнительной таблицы - так она, на мой взгляд, лишняя, добавьте поле в таблице и поставьте значение по умолчанию - время обновления строки,  вот и все)

Если я правильно понял, что вам надо.